# Issue when resizing browser windows

Tags: html, css

I'm having a strange issue on one of my website which is driving me mad.

When you resize the browser window to the point where you get the scroll bars a white void is created.  It seems to be coming from the body tag but I can seem to figure out why.

Update : the website addess is http://www.computerrepairssolihull.co.uk/

[image: White Void]

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the element with **firebug** or similar?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Firefox/Mac. What browser/OS do you use?

Comment: Google Chrome, Firefox(may be a older version) and IE9

Comment: You resizing the window so you get the scroll bar at the bottom

Comment: I generated the issue in IE9. Maximised window is fine but when you resize it the colours get all out of sync.
Use firefox/chrome with firebug and check for div width issues within your CSS.

Comment: No errors occured like you explained, with Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94) and InternetExplorer 7,8 and 9 on Windows Vista x86

Comment: I have tried inspect Element in Chrome.  Seems to be related to the Body tags.  I'll looked at this bug for about 20minute without success.

Comment: Thanks to all who spent the time helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in that all your "content-pad" classes doesnt have the width of the page.

As soon as i give it a width it works fine.

Comment: Yes this solved it mostly.  They was other issue with the css which wasn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your layout to use a [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) framework such as Foundation or Gumby.